# How to select multiple dates on android calender view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar

```
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(2022, 5, 10)
    val dateSelected = calendar.timeInMillis

    val calender2 = Calendar.getInstance()
    calender2.set(2022, 5, 11)
    val dateSelected2 = calender2.timeInMillis
    
    binding?.calenderView?.setDate(dateSelected, true, true)
    binding?.calenderView?.setDate(dateSelected2, true, true)
```

I've tried to select two dates as shown above, but it doesn't work? Any help?

Comment: That is not a feature of the Android SDK's `CalendarView`. There are [many calendar widgets available from other developers](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created). One or more of them may offer what you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            val dateRangePicker =
            MaterialDatePicker.Builder
                .dateRangePicker()
                .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar)
                .setTitleText("Title")
                .setSelection(
                    Pair(
                        MaterialDatePicker.thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(),
                        MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()
                    )
                )
                .build()

        dateRangePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "tag")
        dateRangePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            println(it.first)
            println(it.second)

        }
```

Comment: The MaterialDatePicker offers no interfaces for Accessibility, so if you are bound by the American's with Disabilities Act, you will be stuck. Trying to find both a functional multidate-selectable calendarview or datepicker...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select range of date, try material date picker [material date picker doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/DatePicker.md)

```
 MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().build().show(supportFragmentManager, "")
```